# Mysql on update and default

Tags: sql, mysql, soundex

I want to have a column on a table that is automatically updated when the row is updated, this column is a soundex version of another column, hypothetically, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (`title` VARCHAR(255), `title_soundex` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT SOUNDEX(`title`) ON UPDATE SOUNDEX(`title`));
```

Something like this is even possible? Is there any other approaches to make this happen solely on mysql without updating the code that uses this table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not using constraints.

You would need to create an on update trigger on the `test` table that would check if the title has been updated, and if so, update the title_soundex field.